# Is there a way to filter out latitude and longitude data that lies outside a specific region? Preferably using Python?

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, gis, latitude-longitude

I want to display a set of nodes that are mapped to the region of Vancouver. However, the dataset that I build on contains nodes that are mapped to other regions such as Burnaby, Richmond, Surrey etc. My data is stored as a collection of csv files, and I want to filter the data parsing through the data so that only those nodes that contain latitude and longitude lying inside the region of Vancouver (marked by a yellow rectangle in the picture below - link specified) are displayed and the others are ignored.
Any leads to this case will be much appreciated!

IMAGE LINK: https://ibb.co/Y8JhWJ4

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will want to apply something like this...

```py
import pandas as pd

LATITUDE_KEY = 'Latitude'
LONGITUDE_KEY = 'Longitude'
columns = [ \
  # stuff and
  LATITUDE_KEY,
  LONGITUDE_KEY
]

nodes = pd.read_csv('place_nodes.csv', names=columns)  
nodes = nodes[nodes[LATITUDE_KEY].between(LAT_MIN, LAT_MAX) \
  & nodes[LONGITUDE_KEY].between(LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX)]
```